# Is translational/rotational KE conserved when diatomic molecules collide?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, particle-physics, conservation-laws, collision, ideal-gas

When two diatomic molecules of a gas collide, is the collision elastic or inelastic? Is rotational KE also conserved/not conserved?

My guess is that translational KE is conserved while rotational KE isn't. I'm just guessing for the translational part, but as for the rotational part I can imagine two molecules "canceling each other out" if one spins clockwise / the other counterclockwise and they bump into each other.

Answer (score 2):

Only the ***total*** energy, linear momentum, and angular momentum are gauranteed to be conserved. Translational kinetic energy can get converted to rotational (and vibrational for that matter), and vice versa. Consider, for example, non-rotating molecules approaching each other in a broadside collision:

[image: broadside collision]